# Convert Spring checkboxes to Spring submit buttons

Tags: spring

Below Spring form submits data to a Spring controller and works as expected.
How can I convert the checkboxes to buttons ? So instead of three checkboxes : 'isTest1,isTest3,isTest3' three buttons are displayed.
This then means instead of having one submit button I have three submit buttons with each button.

Here is my form currently :

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="searchobj" action="redirect">


    <table>

     <tr>
        <td><form:input path="param" /></td>  
        <td><input type="submit" value="Search"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<table>
    <td>isTest1</td>
    <td><form:checkbox path="isTest1" /></td>

    <td>isTest2</td>
    <td><form:checkbox path="isTest2" /></td>


    <td>isTest3</td>
    <td><form:checkbox path="isTest3" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>  

 </center>

</form:form>
```

I've tried linking the form directly to the submit button so instead of

```
<td><form:checkbox path="isTest1" /></td>
```

use

```
<td><input type="submit" value="isTest1"/></td>
```

but I dont how to access the value in the controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used :

```
  <form:input type="submit" path="myPath" value="Tester"/>
```